# Joomla | Module internationalization | New developer

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I try to create a very simple module in Joomla. While my whole code is correct, and the module working properly, I cannot make it  support the I18n feature.

More specific, my module directory is like that:

```
mod_mymodname:
    languages:
        en-GB.mod_mymodname.ini
    mod_mymodname.php
    mod_mymodname.xml
```

and then in my mod_mymodname.xml I have that code :

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5.0" client="site">
    <name>MyModName</name>
    ... Other Options ...
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_mymodname">mod_mymodname.php</filename>
        <filename>mod_mymodname.xml</filename>
    </files>
    <languages folder="languages">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_mod_mymodname.ini</language>
    </languages>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="modid" size="50" type="text" label="MODID" description="Description here" />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extensions>
```

and my en-GB.mod_mymodname.ini has that content in it

```
MODID=Module ID
```

The problem is that in my admin section the field label has the value of "MODID" instead of "Module ID"

Is there anything wrong with that ? Is my first Joomla module, and I am not sure if everything is correct.

**Note** : The module doesn't require any translation in the front-end. I only need I18n for the administration section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you mentioned correct text for MODID in language file.

```
en-GB.mod_mymodname.ini ---> This file was used for declaring the text what we given in that module
```

- Just add the following line in **en-GB.mod_mymodname.ini** this language file.

MODID="Module ID"

Save and check the module.. Hope this will work....

Comment: I just did it, but no effect :(

Comment: Please check the language file was added in that folder (administrator/languages/en-GB/). If it was not there you have to create new language file with same name which you mentioned in the XML file

Answer (score 2):

language file need to be in joomla language folder. If you had installed the module from admin then check the language folder and check if your file exists there.

check in administrator/languages/en-GB/

also you may have to change the way you have mentioned language files in your xml.

Have a look at this link for more detailed description

http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files#Language_file_naming_conventions_and_precedence

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also have en-GB.mod_mymodname.sys.ini for translating text coming from the xml.

I thought of something else too. There does seem to be a known issue where for certain strings from the xml are only translated when the language file is in the main language folder rather than the extension language folder.  So I usually put copies both places even though it's considered bad practice to put extension files in the core folder.

Answer (score 1):

first add your module.xml language tag

```
<languages folder="languages">
    <language tag="fr-FR">fr-FR.mod_mod_mymodname.ini</language>
    <language tag="fr-FR">fr-FR.mod_mod_mymodname.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

then create two new file in your module language folder
         fr-FR.mod_mod_mymodname.ini
         fr-FR.mod_mod_mymodname.sys.ini
add the text you want to translate in .ini file like
       MOD_MYMODULE_USERNAME="this is my mod"

Then add this constant value to your module default.php file like
       JText::_ ('MOD_MYMODULE_USERNAME')